# Proper error handling for kafka batch listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am working on error handling implementation and have a question.
Let me explain the problem:
I receive a batch of messages, I do the DB lookup of each one in the for loop, then I need to collect all the looked up objects in the list and call bulk insert stored proc and bulk update stored proc with this list of objects.

Now let's assume there is some exception happened during lookup. I want to retry this message. For this case I tried to use `DefaultErrorHandler`. But there is a problem, according to the doc, when BatchListenerFailedException with element index is thrown it commits the offsets of the records before the index. But as I said I need to execute bulk insert and update after lookup so I don't want to commit offsets before the index, these records weren't inserted/updated to the DB yet.

Does it mean that my only option is to use `RetryingBatchErrorHandler` that retries the whole batch every time? Can I somehow continue processing messages that don't produce an error?

Also if `RetryingBatchErrorHandler` is the only option, how could I be sure that in case of long backoff period (exponential backoff), kafka won't kill my consumer and won't initiate rebalance?

My current implementation:

```
RetryingBatchErrorHandler retryingBatchErrorHandler =
                new RetryingBatchErrorHandler(backoff,
                        (consumerRecord, e) ->
                                log.error("Backoff attempts exhausted for the record with offset={}, partition={}, value={}, offset committed.",
                consumerRecord.offset(), consumerRecord.partition(), consumerRecord.value()));

factory.setBatchErrorHandler(retryingBatchErrorHandler);
```

UPDATE: see comments in the Artem's answer.
This is how lookup step can be wrapped into `retryTemplate`

```
LookedUpRequest lookedUpRequest = retryTemplate.execute(ctx -> {
   //Lookup step
   return lookup.process(request);
});
```

and if it fails then it will throw the exception further for batch error handler where `RetryingBatchErrorHandler` retry the batch according to its policy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See its JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * A batch error handler that invokes the listener according to the supplied
 * {@link BackOff}. The consumer is paused/polled/resumed before each retry in order to
 * avoid a rebalance. If/when retries are exhausted, the provided
 * {@link ConsumerRecordRecoverer} is invoked for each record in the batch. If the
 * recoverer throws an exception, or the thread is interrupted while sleeping, seeks are
 * performed so that the batch will be redelivered on the next poll.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 2.3.7
 *
 */
public class RetryingBatchErrorHandler extends KafkaExceptionLogLevelAware
        implements ListenerInvokingBatchErrorHandler {
```

So, no rebalance because consumer is paused in between.

You might need to think about something caching for your lookup part, so you don't stress DB with those records which you have requested already before the failure.

You also may think about doing a retry around that lookup yourself. See `RetryTemplate`. But in this case you need to be sure that the whole operation is not long enough (see `max.poll.interval.ms`) to make a consumer to leave its group.

Comment: I see that RetryTemplate was deprecated in the latest version, so I just used RetryingBatchErrorHandler with exponential backoff to retry the whole batch. Looks like that's my only option. It's sad that RetryingBatchErrorHandler doesn't support exceptions classifications. I added the code how I implemented it right now. Thank you for confirming that consumer won't be killed.

Comment: The `RetryTemplate` is not deprecated. It is just its functionality is replaces by the `RetryingBatchErrorHandler` in the Kafka listener container. You have missed my point: I suggested you to use a `RetryTemplate.execute()` directly in your code to avoid pushing an exception back to Kafka listener container. But that's only for the lookup functionality: I wouldn't wrap to my own retry an insert and update...

Comment: now I get it, I wrapped lookup operation with retryTemplate.execute, thanks! But why you wouldn't suggest wrapping insert and update?

Comment: Because you said it yourself: it is a single operation for the whole batch. So, let Kafka container to bring it back to you as a whole batch with its own retry feature.

Comment: but in this case it will have to go through lookup again

Comment: That's why I suggest to take a look into caching feature: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache. So, when you call lookup for the same params, it will pull the value from the cache - won't go to DB or external service.

Comment: got it, thank you Artem!